# Handling colon in element ID with jQuery

Tags: jquery

We are not able to access the div element with ID "test: abc" in JS code using jQuery.

```
<div id="test:abc">

$('#test:abc')
```

It's working fine without colon. We do not have control on ID generation as it is auto generated in Trinidad sub forms because it attaches sub form ID with `:` to every element inside it.

Comment: basically it is good nothing was accepted, because the best answer is eventually not the top rated one (hint: check my answer)

Comment: I'm glad you found a solution, Trinidad sub forms need to sort out their naming conventions.

Comment: IBM Domino (xpages) does the same thing. It's really jquery that's the problem, given that a colon is legitemate ID text.

Answer (score 215):

You need to escape the colon using two back-slashes:

```
$('#test\\:abc')
```

Answer (score 90):

**In short**

`$(document.getElementById("test:abc"))` is what you should use.

**Explanation**:
Apart from the speed gain (see further down), it is easier to handle.

Example: Say you have a function

```
   function doStuff(id){

       var jEle = $("#" + id); //is not safe, since id might be "foo:bar:baz" and thus fail. 
       //You would first have to look for ":" in the id string, then replace it

       var jEle = $(document.getElementById(id)); //forget about the fact 
      //that the id string might contain ':', this always works
    }

    //just to give an idea that the ID might be coming from somewhere unkown
    var retrievedId = $("foo").attr("data-target-id");
    doStuff(retrievedId);
```

**Speed / Timing**

have a look at this [jsbin which tests and compares the speed of selection methods of IDs with colons](http://jsbin.com/ujajuf/4/edit)

you need to open your firebug console to get the results.

I tested it with firefox 10 and jquery 1.7.2

basically I did a select 10'000 times of a div with a colon in the id - with the different methods to achieve it. Then I compared results to a ID selection with no colon in it, the results are quite surprising.

left time in ms
right selector method

```
299 $("#annoying\\:colon")

302 $("[id='annoying:colon']"

20 $(document.getElementById("annoying:colon"))


71 $("#nocolon")

294 $("[id='nocolon']")
```

especially

```
  71 $("#nocolon") and
299 $("#annoying\\:colon")
```

comes a bit as a surprise

Comment: This is really useful and should be upvoted more. Even though this, $("[id='annoying:colon']", works. document.getElementById seems to be what should be used.

Comment: Simply using a more complicated code to archive the same result just because it's faster is a case of premature optimization. You should always prefer readable code over fast code unless it's a performance bottleneck.
Or in the word of [Wiliam Wulf](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/William_Wulf): "More computing sins are committed in the name of efficiency (without necessarily achieving it) than for any other single reason – including blind stupidity." More info [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_optimization).

Comment: Seems to be better with newer jQuery (2.1.1):  
**32** `$("#annyoing\\:colon")`, **29** `$("[id='annyoing:colon']")`, **5** `$(document.getElementById("annyoing:colon"))`, **8** `$("#nocolon")`,
**31** `$("[id='nocolon']")`

Comment: @Möhre that's good to hear. Sadly IE8 is still an issue (and not supported by jQuery 2). But the countdown for IE8 is ongoing http://theie8countdown.com/

Comment: @nfechner. What is more readable in your opinion? `$("#annoying\\:colon")` or `$(document.getElementById("annoying:colon"))` ?

Comment: @JakubGodoniuk I like (as in personal preference) the first version for its brevity. I've also not seen an real-life example where the speed difference has any relevance. It sounds a bit like [premature optimization](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization).

Answer (score 32):

It's tripping up on the colon, obviously, because jQuery is trying to interpret it as a selector.  Try using the id attribute selector.

```
 $('[id="test:abc"]')
```

Answer (score 10):

I would just use `document.getElementById`, and pass the result to the `jQuery()` function.

```
var e = document.getElementById('test:abc');
$(e) // use $(e) just like $('#test:abc')
```

Answer (score 7):

use two backslash `\\`

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/wjwRb/2/)

as written here

> If you wish to use any of the
> meta-characters ( such as
> !"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@[]^`{|}~ ) as a
> literal part of a name, you must
> escape the character with two
> backslashes: \. For example, if you
> have an element with id="foo.bar", you
> can use the selector $("#foo\.bar").
> The W3C CSS specification contains the
> complete

[Reference](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

Answer (score 4):

Referring to Toskan's answer, I updated his code to make it a bit more readable and then output to the page.

Here's the jbin link: 
http://jsbin.com/ujajuf/14/edit.

Also, I ran it with more iterations

```
Iterations:1000000

Results:    
12794   $("#annyoing\\:colon")
12954   $("[id='annyoing:colon']"
754 $(document.getElementById("annyoing:colon"))
3294    $("#nocolon")
13516   $("[id='nocolon']")
```

Even More:

```
Iterations:10000000

Results:    
137987  $("#annyoing\\:colon")
140807  $("[id='annyoing:colon']"
7760    $(document.getElementById("annyoing:colon"))
32345   $("#nocolon")
146962  $("[id='nocolon']")
```

Answer (score 3):

try using `$('#test\\:abc')`

Answer (score 1):

This syntax `$('[id="test:abc"]')`
worked for me. I'm using `Netbeans 6.5.1` & it generates components with an `id` that contains a `: (colon)`. I tried the `\\` & the `\3A` but none of them worked.

Answer (score 0):

Use `$('[id=id:with:colon]')`.