# Selecting an ID with a colon in it with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, identifier

I'm working on a pre-written module for a site, and I need to target an element with the id `test:two`. Now, this element has a colon in it, so jQuery is presumably and understandably seeing the 'two' as a pseudo class. Is there any way of targeting this element with jQuery?

Also, changing the ID is not possible. Believe me, if I could I would.

I've put together an example:

```js
$('#test').css('background','red');
$(document.getElementById('test:two')).css('background','blue');
$('#test:two').css('background','green');
```

```html
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.3.js"></script>

<div id="test">test</div>
<div id="test:two">test two</div>
```

Comment: As an alternative to escaping, you can retrieve the DOM element using getElementById and then wrap it in jQuery. eg. `$(document.getElementById('test:two'))`. This technique an be useful in other cases as well.

Comment: I did some testing, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11862160/533426

Comment: Duplicate of: [Handling colon in element id jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5552462)

Comment: Consider using $.escapeSelector instead of manually escaping. https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.escapeSelector/

Answer (score 87, accepted):

Simply escape the colon with a `\\`:

```
$('#test\\:two');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zbX8K/3/

---

See the docs: **[How do I select an element by an ID that has characters used in CSS notation?](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-select-an-element-by-an-id-that-has-characters-used-in-css-notation/)**.

Answer (score 18):

From [the jQuery ID Selector docs](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/):

> If the id contains characters like periods or colons you have to [escape those characters with backslashes](http://docs.jquery.com/Frequently_Asked_Questions#How_do_I_select_an_element_by_an_ID_that_has_characters_used_in_CSS_notation.3F).

Because the backslash itself need to be escaped in the string, you'll need to do this:

```
$("#test\\:two")
```

```js
$('#test').css('background','red');
$(document.getElementById('test:two')).css('background','blue');
$('#test\\:two').css('background','green');
```

```html
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.3.js"></script>

<div id="test">test</div>
<div id="test:two">test two</div>
```

You now also have the option of using the built-in `CSS.escape(...)` function, which takes care of any characters that could have special meaning inside of a selector expression.

```
$("#" + CSS.escape("test:two"))
```

```js
$('#test').css('background','red');
$(document.getElementById('test:two')).css('background','blue');
$("#" + CSS.escape("test:two")).css('background','green');
```

```html
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.3.js"></script>

<div id="test">test</div>
<div id="test:two">test two</div>
```

Answer (score 13):

Use the [attribute equals selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/).

```
$('[id="test:two"]')
```

Comment: My *guess* is that this would perform worse than the accepted answer. Any idea if that's the case?

Comment: @Kip: Possibly, it was just another suggestion.

Comment: Thanks, that helped.

Answer (score 7):

Try using an attribute selector

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('div[id="test:two"]').each(function() {
       alert($(this).text());
    }); 
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zbX8K/2/