# Change value of an input field using its id value in jquery not working

Tags: jquery, html

I would like to change value of an input field. I get the id value of the input tag through some iterations. Then I used val() to give a value. 
But it's not working.

**My HTML is**

```
<input type="text" id="shipping:firstname" name="billing[firstname]" value=""/>
```

**My jQuery is**

```
$(window).ready(function(){
var text_to_get='firstname';
var targetID = '#shipping['+text_to_get+']';
$(targetID).val("10");
});
```

jsFiddle is at: [here](http://jsfiddle.net/velmurugansp/4jPKa/)

Waiting for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(window).ready(function(){
    var text_to_get='firstname';
    var targetID = '#shipping\\:'+text_to_get;
    $(targetID).val("10");
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sBqxp/1/

to escape colon char use "\\"
But, I think put colon on ids or names or whatever is a bad idea 
(use camelCase notation : id="shippingFirtName")

ref:
[Jquery selecting an ID with a colon in it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7434215/jquery-selecting-an-id-with-a-colon-in-it)

Comment: Thanks @dirtyoldtown.
i was trying to change the value with "name" value. Shame of myself :(

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
var text_to_get = 'firstname';
var targetID = '#shipping\\:' + text_to_get;
$(targetID).val("10");
```

You need to escape this `:` in the **targetID** since, it will give a error in the console like:

> Syntax error, unrecognized expression: unsupported pseudo: firstname

Answer (score 0):

Here you go!!

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
      var text_to_get='firstname';
      var targetID = '#shipping:['+text_to_get+']';
      $(targetID).val("10"); 
    });
```