# Can't remove div with id using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

After an Ajax request, I want that the div with the ID disappeard but it doesn't work. There is no error in the console log. I've checked the condition after the ajax request with an `alert()` and it works so this is the `remove()` function wich doesn't work.

**My div** (it contains a lot of content like divs)

```
<div class="div_avion" <?php echo ($demandePHP==true)?'id="avion_idDIV:'.$dataPHP['avion_id'].'"':'';?> <?php echo ($demandePHP==false)?'style="display:none;"':'';?>>...</div>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $(document).on('click', '.button-trash', function() {
            if($(this).is(".avion_bdd"))
            {
                var avion_id = $(this).attr('id').replace("avion_id:", "");
                var result = confirm("Etes-vous sûr de vouloir supprimer cet avion ?");
                if (result) {
                    $.ajax({
                       url : '<?php echo 'http://'.$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST].'/scripts/deleteavionflottehub.php';?>',
                       type : 'POST', // Le type de la requête HTTP, ici devenu POST
                       data : 'avion_id='+avion_id,
                       dataType : 'html',
                       success : function(resultat, statut){
                        if(resultat=='OK')
                        {
                            $('#avion_idDIV:'+avion_id).remove();

                        }

                       },

                       error : function(resultat, statut, erreur){

                       },

                       complete : function(resultat, statut){

                       }
                    });
                }

            }else{
                $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().remove(); 
            }
        });
});
```

Have you an idea?

Comment: The colon in your `id` is interpreted as a pseudo class/selector and therefore nothing is found. Here's the solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7434215/jquery-selecting-an-id-with-a-colon-in-it

Comment: Is this `$(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().parent()` suppose to be getting the `div_avion` element?  An easier way to do this would be to do `$(this).closest('.div_avion')` .. But I am not really clear as to what you are trying to remove. Can you add the relevant HTML?

Comment: @Joe Indeed it has solved my problem. thx

Comment: @KrisHollenbeck It was not my question but I've tried your suggestion and it's more simple so thx.

Answer (score 1):

In jQuery selector-syntax the `:` has a special meaning, see here for some examples: https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/basic-filter-selectors/ . In your example it seems to be part of an ID-string: `'#avion_idDIV:'+avion_id`. You may have to look into some other way of forming your ID-strings.

**Sorry!** just noticed, Joe has already mentioned this point 10 mins ago! I did not mean to regurgitate his post. It is Joe who deserves the credits for this answer.