# How to retrieve an element with getElementById and then extend it to use Prototype methods?

Tags: javascript, prototypejs, getelementbyid

I have an input element with id `billing:postcode`. The Prototype $() selector is unable to select this element as described in [this ticket](https://prototype.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8886/tickets/497-prototype-v1603-elementselect-works-wrong-under-safari-and-chrome).

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5552525/507369) solution for the same problem in jQuery. I can't get it to work in Prototype. I tried:

```
var element = document.getElementById('billing:postcode');
Element.extend(element);
element.invoke(...);
```

and:

```
var element = document.getElementById('billing:postcode');
$(element).invoke(...);
```

Both don't work: `Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLInputElement> has no method 'invoke'`

I know I can get the element with the CSS selector like this:

```
$$('#billing\\:postcode')
```

But I want to use getElementById

Comment: Why the "not a real question" close vote? The question is quite clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `Element.extend(element);` works, although the most common way is to just pass it through `$()`:

```
var extended = $(document.getElementById('billing:postcode'));
```

But note that single elements don't have the Prototype [`invoke`](http://api.prototypejs.org/language/Enumerable/prototype/invoke/) method, which is the real problem you're running into. :-) `invoke` is part of [`Enumerable`](http://api.prototypejs.org/language/Enumerable), which only applies to lists of elements, not individual ones — its purpose is to call a given function on each element in the list. Rather than calling `invoke`, just call the function you're trying to invoke directly.