# Using variable containing colon, ':,' as a selector

Tags: jquery, variables, jquery-selectors

I have a jQuery variable that I wanna use as the selector. The variable contains colon, ':', as seen in the example below.

```
var testVariable = text1:text2:4882746225
```

The variable id used as the **id** of a **div** element and I cannot remove the colons. There is another **div** element inside the parent div. Below you can see how it looks.

```
<div id="text1:text2:4882746225">

<div class="inner">
Sample content
</div>

</div>
```

What I want to do is to select the inner div element, which has the class **inner**, via the parent div's id. I have tried the following but it didn't work.

```
$('#'+testVariable+' .inner')
```

Does anyone else have run into a similar problem? If so, what is the solution? What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have a look here for detailed informations http://stackoverflow.com/a/11862160/533426

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape those special characters with a double backslash `\\`.

```
var testVariable = "text1\\:text2\\:4882746225";
```

---

update (in response to comment):

But you can access it at some point right? Well then we have to work a little harder and punch the duck for as long as we need. Like

```
var newSelector = $('div').attr('id').replace(/:/g, '\\\\:');
```

and then use `newSelector` to select

```
$(newSelector);
```

Comment: Hey jAndy, I forgot to state that I am not allowed to edit the variable. Have to use it as it is. Just edited the question.