# jQuery get elements that contain form in id

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, background

I am trying to get an element from my page using jquery :

The element :

```
<a href="path" id="form1:ctlName">
```

I am trying to get the element like this and fail :

```
$('#form1:ctlName')
```

While this way works :

```
document.getElementById('form1:ctlName');
```

The problem is that I need the .css property which is jquery only.

Anyone has any idea how to get the control using jquery?

Comment: From the [**documentation**](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/): *"To use any of the meta-characters ( such as  ``!"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@[\]^`{|}~`` ) as a literal part of a name, it must be escaped with with two backslashes: ``\\``.*" `:` is a meta-character.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Handling colon in element id jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5552462/handling-colon-in-element-id-jquery)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem comes with the `:` in your selector, since [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) tries to interpret it as a  extension for the selectors. Some uses of the colon for selector are the pseudo classes `:first` or `:last`, you can get a full list of those selector extensions can be found [here](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/jquery-selector-extensions/).

Try these selectors:

```
$("[id='form1:ctlName']"); //Method one, encapsulating the id
$("#form1\\:ctlName");     //Method two, escaping the colon
```

Here's a working [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/KLjvc/)

Note that according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11862160/363262), calling the native javascript method `getElementById(yourId)` would be about **10x faster** than the other methods, so if performance is paramount you may want to consider using that.

Answer (score 2):

that's because the ':' has a special meaning in jQuery. You should escape it.

```
$('#form1\:ctlName'); // Does not work
```

Apparently you should escape it with two slashes:

```
$('#form1\\:ctlName'); // Works
```

Answer (score 2):

More performant than the other answers (looping through all elements to check the ID attribute), is this way:

```
$(document.getElementById('form1:ctlName'))
```

jQuery is just a function that wraps DOM elements. You can pass DOM elements to it with no issue.

Answer (score 1):

Escape the : with two "\"

```
$('#form1\\:ctlName')
```

-With one "\", it does not work. http://jsfiddle.net/m8Vrt/
 -With two "\", it works http://jsfiddle.net/eQT6w/1/

Answer (score 0):

try this out

```
<a href="path" id="form1_ctlName">
$('#form1_ctlName')
```

just replace the : with _

: is restricted char in jquery selectors 
check this url

http://api.jquery.com/animated-selector/