# Javascript select element with complicated ID

Tags: javascript, jquery

need some help! am trying to get the value of the below input id "j_id0:j_id2:j_id4:j_id54:0:j_id59:0:j_id63" and have tried jquery and javascript such as: `document.getElementById("j_id0:j_id2:j_id4:j_id54:0:j_id59:3:j_id63")` but keep getting a null result. ID can't be changed either, any help appreciated

```
<td class="sf42_cell_bottom_light"><span id="j_id0:j_id2:j_id4:j_id54:0:j_id59:0:j_id61"><input id="j_id0:j_id2:j_id4:j_id54:0:j_id59:0:j_id63" maxlength="200" name="j_id0:j_id2:j_id4:j_id54:0:j_id59:0:j_id63" size="20" type="text" value="717474417"></span></td>
```

Comment: have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5552462/handling-colon-in-element-id-with-jquery

Comment: Got there just before me Mr Chips. That'll solve this.

Comment: working here with jQuery:: http://jsfiddle.net/pR6Au/

Comment: The element's ID ends with `3:j_id63` and you seem to be using `0:j_id63` in your code. Of course that cannot work.

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
$("[id='j_id0:j_id2:j_id4:j_id54:0:j_id59:0:j_id61']")
```

By the way, since you are apperently using JSF, this is a good practice to set id to each component to avoid such horrible ids (who can changes if you add/remove components).

See more information in this thread:

- [Handling colon in element ID with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5552462/handling-colon-in-element-id-with-jquery)

Comment: Thanks Laurent, have already tried that method but still getting 'null'

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any control of the element? Can you add a class to it?

```
var val= document.getElementsByClassName("TheClassName");
```

Or you can get the TD with class sf42_cell_bottom_light (if it is unique) then get its INPUT elements by:

```
var theTd= document.getElementsByClassName("sf42_cell_bottom_light");
var val =  theTD.getElementsByTagName("INPUT");
```

I need to see more of the HTML to give you an better answer.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to escape `colon` in your id .So

try this

```
 function RemoveInvalidCharacter(myid) {
        return '#' + myid.replace(/(:|\.|\[|\])/g, "\\$1");
    }
```

And call like this

```
$(RemoveInvalidCharacter('j_id0:j_id2:j_id4:j_id54:0:j_id59:0:j_id61'));
```

Have a look at [How do I select an element by an ID that has characters used in CSS notation](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-select-an-element-by-an-id-that-has-characters-used-in-css-notation/)

Answer (score 0):

I have tested this code:

```
   <td class="sf42_cell_bottom_light">
<span id="j_id0:j_id2:j_id4:j_id54:0:j_id59:0:j_id61">
<input id="j_id0:j_id2:j_id4:j_id54:0:j_id59:0:j_id63" maxlength="200" name="j_id0:j_id2:j_id4:j_id54:0:j_id59:0:j_id63" size="20" type="text" value="717474417">
</span>
</td>


<script type="text/javascript">
    document.write(document.getElementById("j_id0:j_id2:j_id4:j_id54:0:j_id59:0:j_id63").value);
</script>
```

in FF, IE, Chrome (the latest versions)... and seems to work ok... ar you sure it is about this id?

Replace:

```
document.getElementById("j_id0:j_id2:j_id4:j_id54:0:j_id59:3:j_id63")
```

with

```
document.getElementById("j_id0:j_id2:j_id4:j_id54:0:j_id59:0:j_id63")
```

The id is different.

http://jsfiddle.net/wNePW/