# initiate datatables on xp:table control

Tags: javascript, datatables, xpages

On an XPage I have a table component:

```
<xp:table id="tblProposals">
```

on which I want to initiate the datatables plugin on via a scriptblock component:

```
<xp:scriptBlock id="scriptInitProposals">
                                <xp:this.value><![CDATA[$(document).ready(function() {

    var tableId = x$("#{id:tblProposals}");
    $("#" + tableId.get(0).id).DataTable();
initProposals("#" + tableId.get(0).id,"getProposals");
    $('table th:first').removeClass('sorting_asc');
});]]></xp:this.value>
                            </xp:scriptBlock>
```

my JS function starts as followed:

```
function initProposals(id, method) {
alert(id)
var db = $(id).DataTable();
db.destroy();
localStorage.clear();

var table = $(id).DataTable({

    "pageLength": pageLength,
    "ajax": "api.xsp/reports?method=" + method,...
```

when I choose a normal html table with id (e.g.  and run scriptblock:

```
<xp:scriptBlock id="scriptInitProposals">
                                <xp:this.value><![CDATA[$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#tblProposals').DataTable();
    initProposals("#tblProposals","proposals");
    $('table th:first').removeClass('sorting_asc');
});]]></xp:this.value>
                            </xp:scriptBlock>
```

The table is generated just fine.

It seems the datatables plugin is not so happy with the dynamic id or am I missing something??

Comment: The main problem is that XPages generate colon's in ID's. these need to be escaped if you want to use them in jquery.... see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5552462/handling-colon-in-element-id-with-jquery

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you get with `x$("#{id:tblProposals}")` is not the id but the DOM jQuery wrapped DOM object already, if I'm not mistaken.

Then, you repeat the `DataTable()` call twice: before calling `initProposals` and inside it. I think you can remove one.

At this point you might want to change what you pass to `initProposals`, either the id or the object, or any of them and then handle it in the method.
You could do something like this:

```
<xp:scriptBlock value="$(document).ready(function() {
        initProposals('#{id:tblProposals}', 'getProposals');
        $('table th:first').removeClass('sorting_asc');
    });"/>
```

Then you slightly modify your function:

```
function initProposals(id, method) {
    var element = $(document.getElementById(id));
    var table = element.DataTable();
    table.destroy();
    localStorage.clear();

    element.DataTable({
```

Comment: Hi Shillem, I know I should not work on Sundays but I just want to thank you for your assistance. Your suggestion does the trick. Must be related to teh DOM.

Answer (score 0):

We are using styleClass property to initialize DataTable plugin. You can try this as an alternative method.

on client side javascript:

```
 $(".dtb").dataTable({
```

on table

```
<xp:table styleClass="table dtb">
```